# NPM not updating

Tags: node.js, npm

Hi i'm trying to update my **npm** to version `8.19.4`, but it won't update from version `6.14.16`.

I tried

```
npm i
npm install -g npm@8.19.4
npm install -g npm@latest (to get any new version)
```

then I do `npm --version` and it's still `6.14.16`. Any thoughts?
my **node** version is `v16.13.0`

Comment: what is the output or error? Please refer to [How to ask question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to properly draft a question

Comment: did you try npm update -g npm ?